# Altium Turn Off Reset Net Colors on Updating .PCBDoc

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I've been working in Altium sporadically, and I like to color my net connections.

Everyone once in awhile I forget to click the option not to reset my net colors when re-populating a .pcbdoc and I wipe out my net colors.

Is there a way in the settings to remove the option of resetting the net colors if you re-populate a board?

Answer (score 1):

- Project -> Options -> ECO  Generation -> Change Net Colors
- Project -> Options -> Comparator -> Changed Net Colors

Depends on what exactly you want.

Comment: Oh yes, beautiful.  I of course did manage to un-color my nets once already re-populating a board because I forget to check the box not to change the net colors.  I never would have found this.